# Why does curl_easy_perform SEGFAULT in my unity test, but not in regular program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am making a small library to make getting data from web API's simple for the rest of my program.

The library `request.c` has 6 functions, 5 "public" and one "private".

1. WriteMemoryCallback (private, copied from [libcurl docs](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html))
2. request_init
3. request_set_headers
4. request_set_url
5. request_fetch
6. request_cleanup

I test all the "public" functions in this order using the [unity testing framework](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity). This causes a segfault on `test_request_fetch`.

But if I make a small program that calls the same functions in the same order, it works just fine.

So what is wrong with my test? I am new to using C. I tried using gdb and targeting valgrind, but even with those tools I am not sure how to debug this.

**EDIT**: In `request.c` file, `request_set_headers` function, commenting out the `curl_easy_setopt` and testing without headers set removes the SEGFAULT and 100% tests pass. I am not sure why this is.

Please let me know if I should add any info or clarify something.

**EDIT**: I have tried to make a minimum reproducible example per Andreas Wenzel's suggestion, but there are many files. I have made a git repo to make running the code easier: CLOSED

### Project folder setup

```
requestlib/
    src/
        request.c
        request.h
    tests/
        includes/ (unity v2.5.2 is here)
        test_request.c
    try/
        simpletest.c
        compile-simpletest.sh
    ex_bin/
        compile.sh
        test.sh
    CMakeLists.txt
```

### request.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include "request.h"


MemoryStruct chunk = {
    .memory = NULL,
    .size = 0
};
CURL *curl_handle = NULL;



static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  MemoryStruct *mem = (MemoryStruct *)userp;
 
  char *ptr = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
  if(!ptr) {
    /* out of memory! */
    printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
    return 0;
  }

  mem->memory = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
  mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
 
  return realsize;
}


int request_fetch(MemoryStruct *putdatahere) {
    if (!curl_handle) {
        return 100;
    }
    int rc = 0;
    putdatahere = &chunk;

    if (chunk.memory != NULL) {
        free(chunk.memory);
    }
    chunk.memory = malloc(1);
    chunk.size = 0;

    
    rc += curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
    rc += curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    return rc;
}


int request_init(void) {
    static int function_runs = 0;
    if (function_runs != 0) {
        return 100;
    }
    function_runs += 1;

    int rc = 0;

    rc += curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    rc += curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    rc += curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    // rc += curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
    rc += curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

    return rc;
}


int request_set_headers(char **headers, int num) {
    if (!curl_handle) {
        return 100;
    }

    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
    int rc = 0;
    char *s;

    for (int a = 0; a < num; a = a + 1) {
        s = headers[a];
        // printf("header set: %s\n", s);
        list = curl_slist_append(list, s);
    }
    
    /// REMOVING THIS LINE TAKES AWAY SEGFAULT ///
    rc = curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_slist_free_all(list);

    return rc;
}


int request_set_url(char *url) {
    if (!curl_handle) {
        return 100;
    }

    return curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
}


int request_cleanup(void) {
    static int function_runs = 0;
    if (function_runs != 0) {
        return 100;
    }
    function_runs += 1;

    if (chunk.memory != NULL) {
        free(chunk.memory);
        chunk.memory = NULL;
        chunk.size = 0;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    curl_handle = NULL;
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

### request.h

```
#ifndef REQUEST_H
#define REQUEST_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

typedef struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
} MemoryStruct;

extern MemoryStruct chunk;
extern CURL *curl_handle;
extern CURLcode res;

// static size_t
// WriteMemoryCallback(void *, size_t, size_t, void *);
int request_init(void);
int request_fetch(struct MemoryStruct *putdatahere);
int request_set_headers(char **, int);
int request_set_url(char *);
int request_cleanup(void);

#endif  // REQUEST_H
```

### test_request.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include "../tests/includes/ex_unity/src/unity.h"
#include "../src/request.h"

void setUp(void) {
    // we don't need any setup
}

void tearDown(void) {
    // don't need any teardown
}


void test_request_init(void) {
    char *failmsg = "request_init SHOULD return 0 AND create a curl_handle that is NOT NULL, but it didn't.";
    int cond;

    int rc = request_init();
    cond = (rc == 0 && curl_handle != NULL);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
    

    failmsg = "On second call, request_init SHOULD return 100, but it didn't.";
    rc = request_init();
    cond = (rc == 100);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
}


void test_request_set_headers(void) {
    char *failmsg = "request_setopt SHOULD return 0, but did not.";
    int cond;

    char *headers[] = {"Content-Type: multipart/mixed"};
    int rc = request_set_headers(headers, 1);
    cond = (rc == 0);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);


    // failmsg = "request_set_headers SHOULD return 100 when curl_handle is NULL, but did not.";
    // CURL *tmpbak = curl_handle;
    // curl_handle = NULL;

    // rc = request_set_headers(headers, 1);
    // curl_handle = tmpbak;

    // cond = (rc == 100);
    // TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
}


void test_request_set_url(void) {
    char *failmsg = "request_set_url SHOULD return 0, but did not.";
    int cond;
    char *url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/undoingtech/Sticky-Steps/main/README.md";
    
    int rc = request_set_url(url);
    cond = (rc == 0);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);


    failmsg = "request_set_url SHOULD return 100 when curl_handle is NULL, but did not.";
    CURL *tmpbak = curl_handle;
    curl_handle = NULL;

    rc = request_set_url(url);
    curl_handle = tmpbak;

    cond = (rc == 100);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
}


void test_request_fetch(void) {
    char *failmsg = "request_fetch SHOULD return 100 when curl_handle is NULL, but did not.";
    CURL *tmpbak = curl_handle;
    curl_handle = NULL;

    MemoryStruct *putdatahere = NULL;
    int rc = request_fetch(putdatahere);
    curl_handle = tmpbak;

    int cond = (rc == 100);  
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);


    /// THIS TEST CAUSES THE SEGFAULT ///
    failmsg = "request_fetch SHOULD return 0 AND chunk size SHOULD be greater than 0, but did not.";
    rc = request_fetch(putdatahere);
    cond = (rc == 0); 
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
}


void test_request_cleanup(void) {
    char *failmsg = "request_cleanup SHOULD return 0 AND set curl_handle to NULL, but it didn't.";
    int cond;

    int rc = request_cleanup();
    cond = (rc == 0 && curl_handle == NULL);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);


    failmsg = "On second call, request_cleanup SHOULD return 100, but it didn't.";
    rc = request_cleanup();
    cond = (rc == 100);
    TEST_ASSERT_MESSAGE(cond, failmsg);
}

// expect 2 "still reachable" leaks due to libcurl 
// it could be libcurl just leaks
// or it could be I set it up wrong
int main(void) {
    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test_request_init);
    RUN_TEST(test_request_set_headers);
    RUN_TEST(test_request_set_url);
    RUN_TEST(test_request_fetch);
    RUN_TEST(test_request_cleanup);
    return UNITY_END();
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(requestlib)

add_library(request STATIC src/request.c)
target_link_libraries(request curl)

include(CTest)

find_program( MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND valgrind )
set( MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND_OPTIONS "--trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --dsymutil=yes" )
set( MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/valgrind_suppress.txt" )

add_executable(test_request tests/test_request.c)

add_library(unity STATIC tests/includes/ex_unity/src/unity.c)
target_include_directories(test_request PUBLIC "tests/includes/ex_unity/src")
target_link_libraries(test_request unity)
target_link_libraries(test_request curl)
target_link_libraries(test_request request)


add_test(
    NAME test_request
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:test_request>
)

if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC )
    target_compile_options(test_request PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra)
endif()
if ( MSVC )
    target_compile_options(test_request PRIVATE /W4)
endif()
```

### compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# get script's directory
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
project_path="$(dirname "$SCRIPT_DIR")"
build_path="$project_path/build-linux"
mkdir -p $build_path

cmake -S $project_path -B $build_path
cmake --build $build_path --config "Debug"
```

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# get script's directory
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
project_path="$(dirname "$SCRIPT_DIR")"
build_path="$project_path/build-linux"
mkdir -p $build_path


(cd $build_path; ctest -D ExperimentalMemCheck -C "Debug" -V)
```

### Partial valgrind output when running with unity

```
1   ==7559== Invalid read of size 8
2  ==7559==    at 0x48C21C8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
3  ==7559==    by 0x4892496: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
4  ==7559==    by 0x48A75FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
5  ==7559==    by 0x48A8465: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
6  ==7559==    by 0x487F03A: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
7  ==7559==    by 0x10C56D: request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
8  ==7559==    by 0x109523: test_request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
9  ==7559==    by 0x10C1BB: UnityDefaultTestRun (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
10  ==7559==    by 0x10964A: main (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
11  ==7559==  Address 0x55752c0 is 0 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 16 in arena "client"
12  ==7559== 
13  ==7559== Invalid read of size 1
14  ==7559==    at 0x48BD6E3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
15  ==7559==    by 0x48C21D5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
16  ==7559==    by 0x4892496: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
17  ==7559==    by 0x48A75FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
18  ==7559==    by 0x48A8465: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
19  ==7559==    by 0x487F03A: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
20  ==7559==    by 0x10C56D: request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
21  ==7559==    by 0x109523: test_request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
22  ==7559==    by 0x10C1BB: UnityDefaultTestRun (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
23  ==7559==    by 0x10964A: main (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
24  ==7559==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
25  ==7559== 
26  ==7559== 
27  ==7559== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
28  ==7559==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
29  ==7559==    at 0x48BD6E3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
30  ==7559==    by 0x48C21D5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
31  ==7559==    by 0x4892496: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
32  ==7559==    by 0x48A75FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
33  ==7559==    by 0x48A8465: curl_multi_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
34  ==7559==    by 0x487F03A: curl_easy_perform (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.7.0)
35  ==7559==    by 0x10C56D: request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
36  ==7559==    by 0x109523: test_request_fetch (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
37  ==7559==    by 0x10C1BB: UnityDefaultTestRun (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
38  ==7559==    by 0x10964A: main (in /media/sf_portal/mono/requestlib/so/build-linux/test_request)
39  ==7559==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
40  ==7559==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
41  ==7559==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
42  ==7559==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
43  ==7559==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

### simpletest.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include "../src/request.h"

void step1(void) {
    request_init();
}

void step2(void) {
    char *headers[] = {"Content-Type: multipart/mixed"};
    request_set_headers(headers, 1);
}

void step3(void) {
    request_set_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/undoingtech/Sticky-Steps/main/README.md");
}

void step4(void) {
    MemoryStruct *putdatahere = NULL;
    request_fetch(putdatahere);
}

void step5(void) {
    request_cleanup();
}

int main(void) {
    step1();
    step2();
    step3();
    step4();
    step5();
    return 0;
}
```

### compile-simpletest.sh (run in try folder)

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o simpletest simpletest.c ../src/request.c -lcurl
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. It would probably be helpful to see how you are setting up the cURL handle in the functions `request_init`, `request_set_headers` and `request_set_url`. For example, did you call `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);` before calling `request_fetch`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made it reproducible, but maybe not minimum. I set the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` in `request_init()` in `request.c`

Comment: I do not think this is not a __minimal__ reproducible example. Do we need all that unrelated code? The error seems to be in `test_request_fetch`. Could you please remove all other code not needed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was in `request.c` in `request_set_headers()`.

```
/// REMOVING THIS LINE TAKES AWAY SEGFAULT ///
rc = curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
curl_slist_free_all(list);  // <-- curl_easy_perform SHOULD BE BEFORE THIS LINE!!
```

1. I set the header with `curl_easy_setopt` and a `curl_slist` that held the header data.
2. Immediately free the data used to set the header with `curl_slist_free_all`.
3. Later in `request_fetch()` call `curl_easy_perform`.

The order according to [this libcurl example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) is supposed to be:

1. Set header.
2. Call `curl_easy_perform`.
3. Free header data with `curl_slist_free_all`.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the reason for the bug. The documentation of [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) states the following: "When this option is passed to curl_easy_setopt, libcurl will not copy the entire list so you must keep it around until you no longer use this handle for a transfer before you call curl_slist_free_all on the list."